# MVC Razor getting Full path on file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to get the full file path using a file browser and send that path as a String using Razor on MVC?I've been using a file selector but this only uploads the file name. Here's the code I have on my cshtml file:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IMG, new { type = "file" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IMG)
```

But this methods only sends the name of the file as a string, not the full path.

For example instead of getting the path "C:\Users\UserMame\Pictures\Test.jpg", it only returns "Test.jpg"

Comment: No, the browsers do not send the full path of a file (for security). The only thing you are going to get is a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing. while saving the image,before saving add full path like

```
string rootpath = "~/Image/MyImages/";//change it according to your requirement
if (img != null)
{
  if (!(Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(rootpath))))
  {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(rootpath));//create a new directory if directory is doesn't exist in the root folder
  }
  string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(rootpath), "Test.jpg");

  img.SaveAs(path);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use MapPath in the controller :

```
model.IMG=Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"+Model.IMg);
```

and then pass the model to view